# HTTPUrlConnection and .torrent file

Tags: java, http, url, download, httpurlconnection

i'm trying to create stand-alone webserver to programmatically search torrent file (ex. from torrentz.eu) and put on download.

I'm totally getting mad by download single torrent file, it seems server response is different using browser or java.

this is the script:

```
      connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies);
                    System.setProperty("http.agent", "");
                    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");

                    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");            
                    connection.setConnectTimeout(22000);
                    connection.setReadTimeout(12000);
                    connection.setUseCaches(false);
                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    connection.connect();
    respCode = connection.getResponseCode();

    if(respCode != 200){
    // do something..
    return false;
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream list = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
stream = connection.getInputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
            int c;
            while ((c = stream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                if(c > 0){
                    list.write(buffer, 0, c);
                }
            }
            list.flush();
            stream.close();
```

this code is good for html, image file, ecc.. but it's impossible to get .torrent files, they are corrupted:

example: UBUNTU torrent, 
https://torcache.net/torrent/B415C913643E5FF49FE37D304BBB5E6E11AD5101/[katproxy.com]ubuntu.14.10.desktop.64bit.iso.torrent

- size of .torrent file downloaded by browser: 44920 byte
- size of .torrent file downloaded by java: 44795 byte
  135 byte are missing! just why??

Comment: How are you writing to the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem!

The file is GZIP compressed!!! probably, browser automatically unzip it by default... thank u very much!